# OAuth: how to set dynamic callback URL?

Tags: angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, angular-ui-router, satellizer

I have incorporated [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) into my app with a variety of social login providers (Facebook, Twitter, Google). My stack consists of: AngularJS (UI Router) and NodeJS/Express.

I seem to be encountering a challenge setting up dynamic callback URLs for user authentication. My app **does not** have a consistent login URL such as `http://example.com/login` because all of my URLs are dynamic and token based, for example: `http://example.com/XH12aT1771`. In effect, my login user experience is a modal overlay and there isn't any consistent login page.

The challenge with my system in integrating with OAuth is after logging the user into my app via the modal overlay, I want to put them back in the exact room (or token) they're in, not redirect them to some callback URL page as this would be a poor user experience.

Is the only way to make my OAuth callback url hardcoded, something like: `http://example.com/success` and then redirect the user back to their token after they hit the `/success` page? Is this really the only way to do such a thing?

Let me know if you need any more question details, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have used 3rd party oauth 2 for some applications, but never found the need  to create static callback urls. It should only match the base url (ie. http://example.com/) and should not bother about what is written after that.

Comment: have you tried setting it to http://localhost?

Comment: Callback URL is usually hardcoded to a specific path.  Maybe you could try having them hit your token route and then reroute them to the callback URL?  I stick to http://passportjs.org/ in my node.js apps so not sure what's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would not know about the options that Sattelizer gives you, and it would also depend on the options supported by the Authorization Server (AS), but:

From a security perspective it is advisable to use a fixed callback URL anyway to prevent some of the attacks that may happen because of either broken/sloppy URL matching on the AS side, or accidental token leakage to 3rd parties on the RP side because of embedded images/iframes on pages that do not consume the token etc.

So regardless of whether there's another way, it would be good security practice to use a fixed callback URL anyway and you can (hopefully) associate the original URL with the state parameter that gets sent out or put it in a cookie and restore it after consuming the token on the callback URL.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Satellizer, but I have built a dynamic url based oauth callback structure.

```
$callback_url = Configure::read('Your.base') . 'connect/provider/signin/' . $invite_code;
```

We oAuth off a unique URL, which puts someone in a specific room.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Satelizer, but after a short read, there seems to be a possibility to configure the callback url after login.

```
// Google
$authProvider.google({
  url: '/auth/google',
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin || window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
  scope: ['profile', 'email'];
  scopePrefix: 'openid';
  scopeDelimiter: ' ',
  requiredUrlParams: ['scope'],
  optionalUrlParams: ['display'],
  display: 'popup',
  type: '2.0',
  popupOptions: { width: 452, height: 633 }
});
```

Here they configure the redirect uri directly to the location, the user is currently at.
See [Satelizer Configuration](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#configuration)

Isn't this the thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer should be either what kfis said or -

```
$authProvider.loginRedirect = '/'; // Change this relative path
```

per - [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#configuration)